# HTML CSS on/off button or recorder switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, curl

Can someone explain/help me how i can achieve the following?;

I'm trying to make a on/off  button in eiter `html/css or java` but I only have just completed a `html/css` course and am lost at this thing.

The thing is that i want is that that button follows two hrefs (one for 'on' and one for 'off')

This button is basicly a recorder button and in the on state it starts a record via a curl and in teh off state it stops the curl.

Preferable I would like to have/create a button similar that this [online button generator](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/)

But I can't figure out how I add the links in the on and the off state.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want it for using in touch devices???

Comment: No, it's basicly for a simple html page but i was rather pleased with the looks of those buttons but i'm not sure if what i want is possible with that generator/code.

Comment: look at [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small function for toggling the `href` attribute . I've build a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7wuZ/) for you. if that what you looking for let me know and I'll help to to build the exact same button as you mentioned in your question.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate, please bear with me as im not proficient with coding and only just have finished a html/css course and just beginning with java and jquery.

I added the html part to my page but im not sure if i need to save that java in a *.js file and add it with a <script> tag?

Comment: You can add js/jQuery code between `<script>` and `</script>` tags. Best place is just before `</body>` tag.

Comment: @user2645886 am sorry but you mean JAVA or JAVASCRIPT these languages are totally different. But i guess we're talking about javascript because you said jQuery. do am right? or simply tell me what you wanna do and I'll do my best to help with it. Cheers

Comment: My apollogies to have confused you, im not sure myself to be honest what language it needs to be or rather say'd:  what language would be best in this situation.

Im looking foor a nice recording button  basicly an on/off switch that opens a popup or target iframe.

in the offstate it has to follow: /control/record/stop?app=live4&name=test
and in the on-start it hast to follow: /control/record/start?app=live4&name=test

Comment: @user2645886 no worries :) Matt. to make the life easier for both of us. Kindly would you tell me what you working on or what are you trying to code for? Thanks.

Comment: Well its basicly a interface to control a rtmp server.

(nginx+rtmp module)

you can start and stop the live streaming records via a curl. And i wanted to make a nice simple foolproof recording button for it..
It's just a small step of what i eventually want to accomplish with that interface but im slowly learning the things i need to know

Comment: well this is java as i guess. with this one i can do nothing with it sorry dude. but i can help to have the on/off button effect if you want.

Comment: To be honest it doesnt matter for me in what language its writen basicly :) Im just looking for a button that works in the way that i described in my previous posts if it's possible?  Your on/off button is basicly what im looking for but the only thing i want it to do extra is that when it shows "on" That it follows: /control/record/start?app=live4&name=test
And if it shows "off" it follows link: /control/record/stop?app=live4&name=test

Comment: there you go check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WSfhK/ and tell me if this the final solution for you. let me know and I'll do that button for you either. Cheers

Comment: and here is it with the styled button http://jsfiddle.net/WSfhK/1/ it looks dirty but its note an issue for now, I just wanna be sure this what you want?

Comment: Im trying to get it to work but for some reason i can not see anything appear on my website. Im not sure what im doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery mobile rather than that, see below

```
// here is HTML
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
       <label for="flipSwitch">Flip toggle switch:</label>
       <select name="flipSwitch" id="flipSwitch" data-role="slider">
          <option value="off">Off</option>
          <option value="on">On</option>
       </select>                  
    </div>
</div>

// you can easily get on/off events and use whatever you want
$("#flipSwitch").on("change",function(){
    var switch = $(this).val();
    if(switch == "on"){        
    }else{
    }   
});
```

jQuery mobile [link](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/sliders/switch.html)

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/22/)

Comment: Thanks for you kind help and code. if you wouldn't mind i already got help for someone else. sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you ? Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/ZQ4hh/)

**HTML**

```
<button id="switch" class="on" data-on="http://google.com" data-off="http://yahoo.com"></button>
```

**CSS**

```
#switch {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.on {
  background: url(on.png) no-repeat;
}
.off {
  background: url(off.png) no-repeat;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $('#switch').wrap('<a href="http://google.com"></a>');        

  $('#switch').click(function() {

    var dataOn  = $(this).attr("data-on"),
        dataOff = $(this).attr("data-off");

      if($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off').wrap('<a href="' + dataOff + '"></a>');

      }
      else if($(this).hasClass('off')) {
        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on').wrap('<a href="' + dataOn + '"></a>');
      }

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for you kind help and code. if you wouldn't mind i already got help for someone else. sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

Again thanks to those who helped me.

Just a quick heads up from my side:

I dropped the styling for now and just went for a functional solution and found it in this way:

```
    <select id="selectbox1" name="2" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;" target="button">
    <option value="/control/record/stop?app=live2&name=test" selected target="button1">Stop recorder</option>
    <option value="/control/record/start?app=live2&name=test" target="button1">Start recorder</option>
    </select>
```

And that works nicely for now.  The only think I'm wondering about is how I can set the target="" to point to an iframe. but it doesn't work on the  tag.

is there someone who knows how I can solve that?